# My int is not taking the value of another int. This is in C, using visual studio

Tags: c, integer

I cannot understand why image[i][j].rgbtBlue in the below code will not take the value of debug_blue_third. I'm probably making a stupid error, but I've been trying to figure it out for hours so any help is really appreciated.

```
                while(x < 9){
                image[i][j].rgbtBlue = debug_blue_third;
                printf("\n image[i][j].rgbtBlue is %i", image[i][j].rgbtBlue);
                printf("\n debug blue first is %i", debug_blue_first);
                printf("\n debug blue second is %f", debug_blue_second);
                printf("\n debug blue third is %i", debug_blue_third);
```

The terminal prints the following.

image[i][j].rgbtBlue is 66

debug blue first is 104000

debug blue second is 322.490295

debug blue third is 322

Comment: It is not productive to try and debug incomplete code snippets. Please provide a complete [mre].

Comment: how is 'rgbtBlue' defined, is it int, char, ...? Same for debug_blue_third

Answer (score 0):

You do not provide the types but seeing your code is very easy to guess.

1. 322 in hex is 0x142
2. 66 in hex is 0x42

so `rgbtBlue` is only one byte long and `debug_blue_third` is at least 2 bytes long. Assigning 0x142 to an unsigned byte will result in 0x42.

Comment: That solved it, rgbtBlue was of type BYTE, thank you very much. 

I'll be sure to include the things needed for minimal reproducible example in future :)